# RegEX Trying to trigger optional search

Tags: regex

So I am using this as a string:

```
Username entry \([a-z]{3,15}
```

To search this as an example:

```
[PA]apf_ms.c:7678 Username entry (host/computer.domain.com) is deleted for mobile a4:c4:94:63:1c:7a
[PA]apf_ms.c:7678 Username entry (username@domain.com) is deleted for mobile 94:e9:6a:ad:14:4d
```

Trying to wrap my head around regex and it's driving me nuts.  My search only gets me so far, I am trying to make host/ optional and can't figure out where to insert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Username entry \((?:host/)?[a-z]{3,15}`

- `(?: ... )` is a non-capture group
- `host/` is what you want to match
- `?` after it means optional

Comment: That worked much better, thank you so much.  Still getting the hang of regex :(

Comment: One of the most useful books I ever read was [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do). There are some great tools too. I occasionally use [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/). Free online alternative: [RegExr](http://regexr.com/). And the makers of RegexBuddy have a great reference site: [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).  And of course @nu11p01n73R pointed out [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sY0vT1/1) -- I'm in no way affiliated with any of those products.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?` make anything optional in regex. The regex can be written as

```
Username entry \((?:host\/)?[a-z]{3,15}
```

- `(?:host\/)?` Matches one or zero `host/`. The `?:` within the brackets prevent it from capturing, as we don't want to save the `host/` for future use.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sY0vT1/1)

Comment: hah! Jinx - I see you chose to escape / which is probably a good idea (depending on the engine)